# Can't login after using ssl in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two wordpress sites running in dedicated server using nginx. I have ssl certificate for *.domain-name.com and I face problems with one site (sub.domain-name.com) running through ssl. I am using really simple ssl plugin. After enabling ssl I can't login to admin area and no errors are shown in logs or console, the site says incorrect password. If I force disable the plugin, I can login using http with same credentials. With disabled plugin https site works, except the login. (Same configuration is used on domain-name.com site and it works without errors).
I tried emptying cache, deleting and reinstalling plugin multiple times without success. Do you have any ideas what can I check?

Comment: close completly your browser before trying to login again.

Comment: I tried this and different browsers as well, but it doesn't solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check what exactly you have in **_options** table in the fields
**siteurl**
**home**
You should have there **https://sub.domain-name.com**

also you need to check your **wp-config.php**. There might be rules added regarding **siteurl** and **home** using incorrect protocol.